# zc.buildout versions

Tags: python, buildout

I have an issue with python egg versions. On my development machine I have `python-ldap` version **2.3.13**, while colleges on their machines have version **2.3.10**. Both `python-ldap` libs are installed on os level.

Is it possible to tell *buildout* not to look for newest `python-ldap` version?

I'm looking for something like this:

```
# using buildout-versions extension
[versions]
python-ldap = any
or
python-ldap => 2.1
```

I would not like to use `buildout -N`, since I'd like to get other egg newest versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buildout only let's you pin (exact) versions by using a `versions` section:

```
[buildout]
versions = myversions

[versions]
python-ldap = 2.3.13
```

where the `versions` key in the `[buildout]` section names a section to be used for the pins (most just call that section `[versions]` as well).

If you need to pin that to a version that differs from machine to machine, you'll have to use a recipe that generates versions based on external parameters.

In the following example I am using the [`mr.scripty` recipe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mr.scripty) to run some python to fetch the version pin for me:

```
[buildout]
versions = versions

[versions]
python-ldap = ${dynamic:python-ldap}

[dynamic]
recipe = mr.scripty
python-ldap =
    ... import subprocess
    ... return subprocess.check_output(
    ...    'dpkg-query', '-W', '-f', '${Version}', 'python-ldap').rsplit('-')[0]
```

The example above uses the `dpkg-query` utility to determine the version of the python-ldap package on Debian or Ubuntu; adjust as needed for your own platform.

Comment: wow that looks smart. I think there is simpler way to get `import ldap; ldap.__version__`.

Comment: @aisbaa: Also fine. :-) Whatever technique works for you, the trick is in using a dynamic part to generate the information in the first place.